# HTTP empty string

Tags: javascript, express, http

I am writing a simple script to send a url to an express server. When I want to console.log the `req.body` I get an empty string, even though I use a parser. Can you help me, getting this to work?

Client

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', logKey);

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/bilder';

var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;

function logKey(e) {
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();

Http.open("POST", API_URL);
Http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
Http.send(JSON.stringify(image));

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
console.log(Http.responseText)
}
}
```

Server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
const port = 8000;


app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());


app.post('/bilder', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send("hello world")
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

Comment: Excuse me, where is Java used here?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `image` isn't an empty string *before* you send it to the server?

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `JSON.stringify` on a string? There's no need to use JSON if all you're passing is a string value. JSON is great for structured data, but you can use `text/plain` for plain text...

Comment: xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); without this you have no body

Comment: i tried it all but i still get an empty string on the server console. And yes, I can print image in the console of the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The problem was in the header of the post and in the parser on the server. i had to add `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` to the post on the client and on the backend i had to use `app.use(express.urlencoded());` as a parser. Using simply express was not efficent. So I learned, that the header needs the same content-type as the parser in the backend.

Thanks alot everyone and best regards